# Retrive Unique Id from the backend while working with React Query Optimistic Update

Tags: reactjs, react-query, mutation, tanstackreact-query

```
const addNewHabit = async ({ userId, habitName, getFullYear }) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL, {
      userId,
      habitName,
      getFullYear,
    });
    return data._id;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};

export const addHabitData = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return useMutation(addNewHabit, {
    onMutate: async (newHabit) => {
      await queryClient.cancelQueries("habits");
      const previousHabitsData = queryClient.getQueryData("habits");

      const id = await addNewHabit(newHabit);

      queryClient.setQueryData("habits", (oldQueryData) => {
        return [...oldQueryData, { ...newHabit, _id: id }];
      });

      return { previousHabitsData };
    },
    onError: (_error, __habit, context) => {
      queryClient.setQueriesData("habits", context.previousHabitsData);
    },
    onSettled: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries("habits");
    },
  });
};
```

I am trying to get _id from the mongodb for implementing the dynamic route for details page. When deal with optimistic update, I don't get Id generate by mongodb which cause my page /undefined because it take some time to re-fetching  by react-query. My current implement works, but it created twice. Are there any other approach?